# How to convert every string element inside an array to ascii and store the results in a new array?

Tags: ruby

This is my first post, but I'm trying to perform a method on every element in an array and store the output of each result into a new array. I'm using ascii conversion. Whenever I run this code, I get "undefined method for codepoints for nil:NilClass" Am I using codepoints incorrectly?

```
def map(array, method)
    result_array = []

    array.each do |element|
        value = element.send(method) # Call the method on the object
        result_array.push(value)
    end

    return result_array
end

def method(x_string)
    x_ascii = x_string.codepoints.to_a
    return x_ascii
    ###Need to finish here
end

Tigers = ['Bengal', 'Asian', 'Burmese', 'Mongolian', 'Cambodian']
result_array = map(Tigers, method)
puts result_array
```

Comment: This code will give a `wrong number of arguments` error, not `undefined method`. Make sure you have posted the actual code you are running.

Comment: When you say "convert to ASCII" do you mean "convert to numeric ASCII character codes"?

Comment: "ascii conversion" doesn't really mean anything.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me :

```
Tigers = ['Bengal', 'Asian', 'Burmese', 'Mongolian', 'Cambodian']

result_array = Tigers.map do |word|
  word.codepoints.to_a
end

puts result_array
```